# How to organize data in AWS S3 bucket during a web data migration?

Tags: node.js, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mern

I currently built a blog using Django. It involves creating a post where images are also uploaded to an AWS S3 bucket.  However, I would like to rebuild the whole website in Node.js/the MERN stack in the near future.  As I upload more photos to the S3 buckets, and build the website in Node.js- how should I keep track of organizing the data that I currently have in Django so that when I have the MERN stack website ready, I can seamlessly move both the post and photo info there?

Comment: can you write a script and insert data from `SQL` db to `mongodb` manually?

Comment: How would I do that? What kind of scripts would I have to use? Can you please specify?